# Prevent administrator from changing account types

Tags: windows-10, administrator

As admin **X**, I want to prevent another user (say, **Y**) from changing the account type of other accounts, but allow them to do all other administrator stuff. Is this possible, and how?

Comment: No. Anything one admin does can be undone by another admin.

Comment: Ok, darn. Is it good practice to self-answer if the answer is "nope, sorry"

Comment: You can self answer if you want ...

Comment: @Blacksilver - If the answer is "nope, sorry" proper research should have caught it before you submitted the question.  Seems like this is an X Y problem, you are trying to prevent an Administrator which has all rights on a Windows machine, from doing something an Administrator can do.

Answer (score 1):

## Nope :(

Sorry, you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

If there was some user type higher than Administrator, then Yes, but none of them let you access the user account